# alert variable outside the scope in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am relatively new to this forum and to jquery as well. So request not to mark negetive incase if my question is wrong.

I had tried to search but still not able to get proper solution for my problem.

I am using change function to get updated unput values as below which is working perfectly fine. I am also able to alert the variable with updated values within the scope as mentioned below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#tags").on("keyup", function() {
    var myVar = $(this).val();
    alert(myVar);
  });
});
```

Now i want to alert the variable myVar outside the scope as below which is not working and i have no idea on how to call this variable out of the given scope. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#tags").on("keyup", function() {
    var myVar = $(this).val();
  });
  alert(myVar);
});
```

Comment: try adding `var myVar = "";` after `ready(function(){`

Comment: I had tried this before posting this question but it is not working. Can you help in posting a solution is JSfiddle? It will help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you try to alert this outside the scope, it will come blank as it will be fired on page load

Instead I think you want to call it inside some event listener as that is why you are trying to assign it to a variable outside it

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var myVar = '';
    $("#tags").keyup(function() {
        myVar = $(this).val();
        alert(myVar);
    });

    //or another event listener {
        alert(myVar);
    });
});
```

Comment: So how to call in another event listner? Can you pease provided updated code?

Comment: that depends on you when you want to alert the value

Comment: The changed values needs to be updated in API url for JSON output. It will not be possible unless we get change values automatically without page refreshing. For updating with change values in url, i need the change value outside the scope to use within another function or event listener.

Comment: @NewsO.Jake yes I understand so what's the issue you are facing. The solution proposed should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store `myVar` somewhere in a scope that can be read by the function that calls `alert`. The sledgehammer approach is to put `myVar` in global scope, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#tags").on("keyup", function() {
       myVar = $(this).val();  //notice no var keyword
   });
});
```

When use a variable without declaring it with `var`, it ends up in global scope-- technically, it becomes a property of the current window. If you wanted to be explicit you could write it as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#tags").on("keyup", function() {
       window.myVar = $(this).val();  //notice no var keyword
   });
});
```

Now in general you should avoid globally scoped variables, since you never know whose variable you might stomp on, e.g. if it has the same name as another variable. So a better solution would be put the variable in a [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp). How that would look depends on exactly where you declare the function that calls `alert`.

Let's say you want to introduce a new global function, `ShowAlert`. You can define this in the same code block using a common variable, which will promoted the variable out of local scope and into a closure, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var myVar;  //We use the var keyword to declare this in local scope, for now

   $("#tags").on("keyup", function() {
       myVar = $(this).val(); 
   });

   ShowAlert = function() {
       alert(myVar);  //Using myVar here forces it into a closure, which will persist even after document.ready has exited
   }
});
```

Then, to show the alert using the latest value of `myVar`, just use:

```
ShowAlert();
```

Comment: But how would the window.myVar return the values outside the scope? Please explain

Comment: Because `window.myVar` is stored outside local scope and in global scope. It can be accessed by code anywhere in the window. That being said, a global variable isn't ideal, so please post the code that needs to *use* `myVar` and I can show you how to access it.

Comment: @John Wu : I want the changed values concatenated to a url for JSON output. Example: https://example.com/suggest?label=changed_input_values&City=NY&f=pjson

Comment: I tried with your update but it is returning undefined statement. Can you please help with a demo in fiddle or any working example for this? That would be most helpful.